# different behavior when using different number of multicoring workers

Tags: windows, r, multicore

I am playing around a bit with my program (trying to multicore a few parts) and I've noticed the "CPU history" looks a bit different, depend on how many workers I start. 2-4 workers seems to produce a "stable" workflow, however pegging 5-8 workers produces erratic behavior (from zero to max, see pictures). I should point out that all runs started out with "smooth" max capacity (e.g. 2 cores with only 25%), and started to exhibit erratic behavior only after a minute or so.
What's going on? I have 4 core processor, and do you think this behavior may be related to this fact?

I hope you can see the pics.

2 workers
[image: 2 workers]

3 workers
[image: 3 workers]

4 workers
[image: 4 workers]

5 workers
[image: 5 workers]

6 workers
[image: 6 workers]

7 workers
[image: 7 workers]

8 workers
[image: 8 workers]

Comment: Are you using the `multicore` package or `doSMP`?  Is this on Windows 7?

Comment: what is the purpose of your workers? are they completely independent of eachother? maybe your workers suffer from starvation.

Comment: Is there a question here?  If so, what is it?

Comment: @Shane: doSMP on W7. I can't get multicore to work for some reason...
@lmre L: ? :)
@Dirk: Last two sentences: What's going on? I have 4 core processor, and do you think this behavior may be related to this fact?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is classic behaviour on a quad-core with hyperthreading. R doesn't gain with hyperthreading, as it uses often the complete core for the calculations. Thus, if one physical processor makes 2 logical ones, the processor has to switch continuously between both threads, which explains the patterns.

For R, I put off the hyperthreading on my computer. It just doesn't help, in contrary. When working with only one thread as R does normally, you lose capacity (max is 12.5% instead of 25%).

Comment: Also remember that by default, a process is not bound to one core but jumps between cores the whole time. This explains why you see the effect you notice gradually increase instead of being obvious on 2 logical cores the moment you have more than 4 workers. It also explains the spiky graphs you inevitably have on a multicore machine.

Comment: I don't buy this explanation. A well written CPU-bound program can make much better use of CPUs.

Comment: @David : what is it you do not buy? The fact that if you have only 4 physical cores and 8 logical cores, the processor has to switch between two threads? How else do you put 2 threads on one core? Simultaneously? Or the fact that -unless you bind a process specifically to one core- the proces itself switches cores whenever it seems feasible?

Comment: R calculations should be Cpu bound and such calculations should get at least 80% utilisation on an i7 system in my experience. I've seen that on a dual quad, i.e. 16 logical cores. The i7 allows 2 threads to make progress at once.

Comment: @David : R works single threaded, and hence doesn't get 80% utilisation on all cores, but 100% utilization on one core. Only one thread, only one (logical) core. Checked it often enough on different computers and servers. That's why all the multicore packages (multicore, snow, snowfall and so on) have to be used.

Comment: yeah I know that. But why can't you
get more out of the multicore
packages?

Comment: With the multicore, you can get 100%. The thing is that if you have 4 physical cores but 8 logical, each physical core is split in two. Each core gets two threads, and switches between them. That's why it seems half of the cores stays idle for a short period. It's not the physical cores that stay idle, it's the logical ones. The physical cores work 100%, each core dividing its power over the two logical ones. This explains the peaky graphs in the pictures.

Comment: @JorisMeys I'm *very* late to the discussion - but I wanted to share my experience. I've long wondered whether R benefits from HT. Some basic testing I've done suggests not - as you mention. That said, I have recently been doing some SVM tuning using mlr3's parallel functionality (which uses the future package) and have found a big difference depending on whether I set workers to physical or logical cores. Maybe it's a quirk of mlr3 and/or future, but it seems like HT can make a difference.