# Multicore and memory usage in R under Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, multicore

I am running R on an Ubuntu workstation with 8 virtual cores and 8 Gb of ram. I was hoping to routinely use the multicore package to make use of the 8 cores in parallel; however I find that the whole R process becomes duplicated 8 times.
As R actually seems to use much more memory than is reported in gc (by a factor 5, even after gc()), this means that even a relatively mild memory usage (one 200Mb object) becomes intractably memory-heavy once duplicated 8 times.
I looked into bigmemory to have the child processes share the same memory space; but it would require some major rewriting of my code as it doesn't deal with dataframes.

Is there a way to make R as lean as possible before forking, i.e. have the OS reclaim as much memory as possible?

EDIT:
I think I understand what is going on now. The problem is not where I thought it was -- objects that exist in the parent thread and are not manipulated do not get duplicated eight times. Instead my problem, I believe, came from the nature of the manipulation I am making each child process perform. Each has to manipulate a big factor with hundreds of thousands of levels, and I think *this* is the memory-heavy bit. As a result, it is indeed the case that the overall memory load is proportional to the number of cores; but not as dramatically as I thought.
Another lesson I learned is that with 4 physical cores + possibility of hyperthreading, hyperthreading is actually not typically a good idea for R. The gain is minimal, and the memory cost may be non-trivial. So I'll be working on 4 cores from now on.

For those who would like to experiment, this is the type of code I was running:

```
# Create data
sampdata <- data.frame(id = 1:1000000)
for (letter in letters) {
sampdata[, letter] <- rnorm(1000000)
}
sampdata$groupid = ceiling(sampdata$id/2)

# Enable multicore
library(multicore)
options(cores=4) # number of cores to distribute the job to

# Actual job
system.time(do.call("cbind", 
    mclapply(subset(sampdata, select = c(a:z)), function(x) tapply(x, sampdata$groupid, sum))
))
```

Comment: "Is there a way to make R lean?" No. Seems to be its biggest weakness.

Comment: can you define your workflow just a bit more? When I've used multicore I've not found the spawned threads to be that big. But you are probably using procedures/methods/workflow I don't use. Can you make some dummy data and illustrate?

Comment: Hi JD. Time to go home here, but I'll update my post asap, probably tomorrow morning. Cheers! (Love your blog and twitter feed by the way.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm coming to blows with multicore today myself. So your question is timely for me too!

Comment: You say hyperthreading. Presumably this is Intel i7?

Comment: That's right -- brand new Sandy Bridge 2600k.

Comment: I got better results by turning hyper threading off. My experience prior to this is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547831/different-behavior-when-using-different-number-of-multicoring-workers

Comment: @crayola Do you have a good chipset and optimally configured memory? 64-bit? My experience with i7 is that 2 threads per core gives significant benefit, but that's with my app rather than R. It seems to me that this version of hyper-threading actually works (unlike the pathetic P4 version).

Comment: @roman Thanks a lot for the link -- very helpful, and confirms my suspicion (hyperthreading not useful for R), though I do NOT observe these weird patterns. The cores seem to work at 100% consistently; just, there is not gain compared to 4 cores. 4 cores > 3 cores > 2 cores > 1 core; but about 4, I hit a ceiling.

Comment: @David I have a good chipset as far as I know (P67 by Intel); 64 bit OS; and no reason to think anything is not well configured on that computer. I agree that the consensus seems to be that with this CPU architecture, the gains from hyperthreading should approach 30%; but somehow this is not reflected in my R experience. I may try to run other benchmarks just to check it's not just me; but I doubt it.

Comment: my number crunching app extracts significant benefit from 2 threads per core. But your memory demands are large.

Comment: @Roman @Crayola The link that Roman referred to concerned doSMP, within process threading. Crayola is using more traditional *NIX based forking. There is often a big difference in performance characteristics.

Comment: Different from where the thread went, but in `tapply(x, f, sum)` the `f` is coerced to a factor and takes about 1/2 the time for each iteration. So making it a factor out of the loop both speeds up the calculation and avoids duplication hence reducing memory use. Also a significant cost of `tapply` is simplifying the result, and we can get a gain by doing this ourselves (at the expense of more brittle code) with `unlist(lapply(split(x, f), sum), use.names=FALSE)`. These lead to a 5-6x speed-up, at least 3 Moore-years of time saved!

Comment: Silly question - but are you sure your memory usage figures are as you state? I suspect there is probably sharing going on - so you can't get a figure for total memory usage by just totting up everything.

Comment: I agree -- I figured this out in my edit. There is indeed some sharing going on, so the problem is not as bad as I initially thought.

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/)?

```
> system.time(ans1 <- do.call("cbind",
lapply(subset(sampdata,select=c(a:z)),function(x)tapply(x,sampdata$groupid,sum))
))
   user  system elapsed 
906.157  13.965 928.645 

> require(data.table)
> DT = as.data.table(sampdata)
> setkey(DT,groupid)
> system.time(ans2 <- DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=groupid])
   user  system elapsed 
186.920   1.056 191.582                # 4.8 times faster

> # massage minor diffs in results...
> ans2$groupid=NULL
> ans2=as.matrix(ans2)
> colnames(ans2)=letters
> rownames(ans1)=NULL

> identical(ans1,ans2)
[1] TRUE
```

Your example is very interesting. It is reasonably large (200MB), there are many groups (1/2 million), and each group is very small (2 rows).  The 191s can probably be improved by quite a lot, but at least it's a start. [March 2011]

---

And now, this idiom (i.e. `lapply(.SD,...)`) has been improved a lot. With v1.8.2, and on a faster computer than the test above, and with the latest version of R etc, here is the updated comparison :

```
sampdata <- data.frame(id = 1:1000000)
for (letter in letters) sampdata[, letter] <- rnorm(1000000)
sampdata$groupid = ceiling(sampdata$id/2)
dim(sampdata)
# [1] 1000000      28
system.time(ans1 <- do.call("cbind",
  lapply(subset(sampdata,select=c(a:z)),function(x)
    tapply(x,sampdata$groupid,sum))
))
#   user  system elapsed
# 224.57    3.62  228.54
DT = as.data.table(sampdata)
setkey(DT,groupid)
system.time(ans2 <- DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=groupid])
#   user  system elapsed
#  11.23    0.01   11.24                # 20 times faster

# massage minor diffs in results...
ans2[,groupid:=NULL]
ans2[,id:=NULL]
ans2=as.matrix(ans2)
rownames(ans1)=NULL

identical(ans1,ans2)
# [1] TRUE
```

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252   LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.2 RODBC_1.3-6
```

Comment: A big mess happens when I try `ans3 <- DT[,mclapply(.SD,sum),by=groupid]`. Any guess?

Comment: @Ryogi Quick guess is that would try and split up each _column_ of .SD. Is that what you wanted? What's the mess?

Comment: Apologies for not following up promptly. Using `mclapply` returns indeed the right answer. What confused me is that (1) it takes *forever*, (2) several messages "select: Interrupted system call" are printed to the R console (in red but are not errors). On second thought, the "taking" forever should have been expected: `mclapply` is called for each single groupid (half a million) and the overhead dwarfs the gains from parallelism. Intuitively, for performance gain DT's columns should be split *before* the `by`.

Answer (score 2):

Things I've tried on Ubuntu 64 bit R, ranked in order of success:

- Work with fewer cores, as you are doing.
- Split the mclapply jobs into pieces, and save the partial results to a database using DBI   with append=TRUE.
- Use the `rm` function along with `gc()` often

I have tried all of these, and mclapply still begins to create larger and larger processes as it runs, leading me to suspect each process is holding onto some sort of residual memory it really doesn't need.

P.S. I was using data.table, and it seems each child process copies the data.table.

Comment: If it were a `data.frame` would it be copied by each child process too? Are you using `data.table` in the way I've used it in my answer, or in a different way? Result of `sessionInfo()` would be good too, to confirm you're using latest versions of various software.

Comment: Well, the question was about the multicore package, so I didn't use data.table exactly like that. I hope eventually data.table uses multiple processors.

Comment: Great package, by the way. Data.table is generally a great solution for most problems. The question was about the multicore package. In my case, I think the system believes that the data.table is modified, and that is why memory increases? I suspect data.frames would do the same. My code is pretty complex, and I'm dealing with 100s of trillions of comparisons between rows in order to produce a 'fuzzy_join'. Another thing I should say, it would be great if one could use arbitrary functions to do fuzzy-joins.

Comment: In the context of this question, the point is essentially footnote 3 of [data.table intro vigentte](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-intro.pdf) (page 5). If you have an appropriate use for `multicore` then that would make a great new question. Please add those new feature requests directly to the [data.table tracker](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240), they sound good. That way you'll get automatic updates when they are discussed or progressed.