# Using plyr, doMC, and summarise() with very big dataset?

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

I have a fairly large dataset (~1.4m rows) that I'm doing some splitting and summarizing on. The whole thing takes a while to run, and my final application depends on frequent running, so my thought was to use `doMC` and the `.parallel=TRUE` flag with plyr like so (simplified a bit):

```
library(plyr)
require(doMC)
registerDoMC()

df <- ddply(df, c("cat1", "cat2"), summarize, count=length(cat2), .parallel = TRUE)
```

If I set the number of cores explicitly to two (using `registerDoMC(cores=2)`) my 8 GB of RAM see me through, and it shaves a decent amount of time. However, if I let it use all 8 cores, I quickly run out of memory due to the fact that each of the forked processes appears to clone the entire dataset in memory.

My question is whether or not it is possible to use plyr's parallel execution facilities in a more memory-thrifty way? I tried converting my dataframe to a `big.matrix`, but this simply seemed to force the whole thing back to using a single core:

```
library(plyr)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
library(bigmemory)

bm <- as.big.matrix(df)
df <- mdply(bm, c("cat1", "cat2"), summarize, count=length(cat2), .parallel = TRUE)
```

This is my first foray into multicore R computing, so if there is a better way of thinking about this, I'm open to suggestion.

**UPDATE:** As with many things in life, it turns out I was doing Other Stupid Things elsewhere in my code, and that the whole issue of multi-processing becomes a moot point in this particular instance. However, for big data folding tasks, I'll keep `data.table` in mind. I was able to replicate my folding task in a straightforward way.

Comment: I guess I'll leave the obligatory comment referring you to the **data.table** package, which is generally much faster at these sorts of things.

Comment: Do you really have 8 cores? Or rather an Intel with 4 cores and 4 "hyperthreading" cores? I have an application running under MPICH (not R) which scales well till 4 at 50% CPU, but runs effectively much slower when 8 cores are requested giving 100% CPU.

Comment: I'll check out the data.table... Sounds promising when people immediately think of one item.

Comment: And yes, my CPU is 4 core with HT. I run out of memory and start swapping above 2, but it sounds like I may not want to use all 8 "cores" even if I can sort out the memory problem. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I had similar problems with "8" cores. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547831/different-behavior-when-using-different-number-of-multicoring-workers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think that plyr makes copies of the entire dataset. However, when processing a chunk of data, that subset is copied to the worker. Therefore, when using more workers, more subsets are in memory simultaneously (i.e. 8 instead of 2).

I can think of a few tips you could try:

- Put your data in to an array structure in stead of a data.frame and use adply to do the summarizing. arrays are much more efficient in terms of memory use and speed. I mean using normal matrices, not big.matrix.
- Give `data.table` a try, in some cases this can lead to a speed increase of several orders of magnitude. I'm not sure if data.table supports parallel processing, but even without parallelization, data.table might be hunderds of times faster. See a [blog post of mine](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/10/28/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/) comparing `ave`, `ddply` and `data.table` for processing chunks of data.

Comment: You might want check that blog post. The three functions you are comparing seem to be doing different tasks: only one of them is calculating a mean as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look! I suspect that it does not change the outcome of the post, namely that data.table is much muhc faster.