# Parallel processing of independent functions with multiple arguments in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have the following function which is a much simpler version of the functions that I have but it pictures what I'm struggling to do.

I follow the discussion here
[Parallelize a function in R (not a loop!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654361/parallelize-a-function-in-r-not-a-loop)
which is a solution for a single argument for each function.

In my case I have the following function `unparal` which has multiple arguments that can be shared across the functions `f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4`

```
f_1 = function(x,y,z){
  return(rnorm(z,x,y))
}
f_2 = function(x,y,z){
  return(rgamma(z,x,y))
}
f_3 = function(x,y,z){
  return(rbeta(z,x,y))
}
f_4 = function(x,y,z){
  return(runif(z,x,y))
}
unparal = function(x,g,t,y,z){
  res1 = f_1(x,g,z)
  res2 = f_2(g,t,z)
  res3 = f_3(t,y,z)
  res4 = f_4(x,y,z)
  res = c(res1,res2,res3,res4)
  return(res)
}
```

What I would like to do is to parallelize the function `unparal`, i.e. to run all the functions `f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4` in parallel. Is there a convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways. One is to use the `future` package. E.g. like so:

```
library(future)

unparal = function(x,g,t,y,z){
  require(future)
  
  res1 %<-% f_1(x,g,z) %seed% TRUE
  res2 %<-% f_2(g,t,z) %seed% TRUE
  res3 %<-% f_3(t,y,z) %seed% TRUE
  res4 %<-% f_4(x,y,z) %seed% TRUE
  res = c(res1,res2,res3,res4)
  return(res)
}

plan(multisession, workers = 4)
unparal(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
plan(sequential)
```

The `%<-%` operator does an assignment, but this is done according to the current `plan`, so in this case in 1 of the 4 workers. Then when the result is accessed (in `res = c(res1,res2,res3,res4)`), the main process will wait till all four results have been returned.

Note the `%seed% TRUE` part is only necessary when you need correct random number generation.

Comment: One more question, the functions can easily be extended to come from C++?

Comment: If you mean whether e.g. `f_1` can call a bunch of C++ code in the background, then yes.

Comment: what I found out, in order to called functions in place of ```f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4``` written in ```Rcpp``, I have to call the library ```Rcpp``` and ```sourceCpp(File Path)```. For the library ```Rcpp``` I can include it within the function, but where do I put the  ```sourceCpp(File Path)```??