# I can't make a sock cluster with doSNOW package (windows)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

i'm trying to use doSNOW package for make `foreach` run parallel but when i run makeCluster function my machine is left running indefinitely and I can not do anything else, help please! I'm using a windows 8 64-bit, intel i3 processors dual core.

```
require(doSNOW) 
require(foreach)

cl.tmp = makeCluster(rep("localhost",2), type="SOCK") 
registerDoSNOW(cl.tmp)

foreach(i=1:4) %dopar% {sqrt(i)}
```

Thanks for your attention, any suggestion is appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm following instructions from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7297008/2806134 but i can not run makeCluster function yet, any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Is you goal to run the code on multiple cores one machine or on several machines? If you just want to use all cores of you local machine I recommend the `doMC` packages instead of `doSNOW`. It is way simpler to get running.

Comment: DoMC package is not available to windows OS :(

Comment: Unfortunately there are many possible problems.  I suggest adding the `makeCluster` `outfile=""` option and executing the code from Rterm.  This may give an error message which would be extremely helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: "C:\Program" not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file. Why?

Comment: Looks like a quoting problem when starting the workers.  What version of snow are you using?

Comment: doSNOW package version 1.0.7

Comment: `makeCluster` is part of "snow", not "doSNOW", so I want to know the version of snow that you're using.

Comment: sorry, version 0.3-13